# SICP Exercise 1.3: Sum of squares of two largest numbers out of three, Haskell Version

Tags: haskell, homework, sicp

The exercise 1.3 of the book [*Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs*](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-10.html) asks the following:

> Exercise 1.3.  Define a procedure that takes three numbers as arguments and returns the sum of the squares of the two larger numbers.

My answer is this:

```
    import Data.List(sort)

    sumSquareLargest :: (Ord n, Floating n) => n -> n -> n -> n
    sumSquareLargest x y z = b ** 2 + c ** 2 where
        [a, b, c] = sort[x, y, z]
```

Am I doing unnecessary work here? How could I improve this answer, even if only stylistically-speaking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't need a value, don't bind it, use a wildcard instead.

```
[a, b, c] = sort [x, y, z] # and btw, add a space after the function name
```

becomes

```
[_, b, c] = sort [x, y, z]
```

---

Perhaps its just personal preference (I don't use much Haskell myself), but I usually see the `where` clause in the next line, with an extra tab, like:

```
sumSquareLargest x y z = b ** 2 + c ** 2
    where [_, b, c] = sort [x, y, z]
```

Moreover, the `b` and `c` values are not obvious at first glance, and you **need** to read the second line before the first. In these cases, a `let` expression can be a more nice alternative:

```
sumSquareLargest x y z =
    let [_, b, c] = sort [x, y, z]
    in b ** 2 + c ** 2
```

---

This is a very small function, but consider having more meaningful names for your bindings:

```
sumSquareLargest x y z =
    let [_, medium, maxim] = sort [x, y, z]
    in medium ** 2 + maxim ** 2
```

---

Also, consider writing some unit tests in a library like QuickCheck.

Comment: I disagree with you on the `where` -- you *always* need to read the `where` in order to understand the code above it, there's noting strange about this code.

Comment: @PatrickCollins most of the times, the `where` isn't that relevant, as in you can abstract the values it produces. This is especially true if the bindings have meaningful names. For example, the classic QuickSort implementation is something like `qsort (x:xs) = qsort lessThanX ++ [x] ++ qsort greaterOrEqualX`, which is possible to understand even without the `where`.